# How to validate the cron expression in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I created a java file in gwt client side to validate the cron expression. Is it possible to use quartz-scheduler to validate the cron expression ?

Answer (score 2):

Validating cron at client side in GWT is not simply easy to go with. You can play with regular expression or with some javascript/jQuery code to achieve that at client side.

But if firing request to server does not cost much to you, you can simply use `quartz` library at server to validate the expression.

You can use `org.quartz.CronExpression` to check whether expression is valid or not with the help of *static* method `isValidExpression(cronExpression)`.

> [`CronExpression#isValidExpression`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#isValidExpression%28java.lang.String%29)
>
> Indicates whether the specified
> cron expression *can be* parsed into a  valid cron expression

Comment: I used the same method by passing a string value which holds cron expression to #isValidExpression available in org.quartz.CronExpression . But i got compilation failure saying  "No source code is available for type org.quartz.CronExpression; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Comment: @SaravananJaganathan Kindly note that quartz resides at the server side and not client side. If you are using it with client side code then it won't work. You have to fire request to server to validate the cron with the help of stated method.